# How to disable a button till the cursor navigates in EditBox field

Tags: android

I have a EditBox for Email and button to go for next page. I put the validation for EditBox to check Email is valid or not and its working fine. My problem is , even i do not fulfill validation criteria  and click on Button ,its go on next page ,which is incorrect.I want to disable  Button if cursor blink in EditBox till validation is not complete. I Goggled so many times but unable to find a solution . Kind suggestion would be appreciated .

Comment: Put a check for empty string as well.

Comment: What does your code look like right now?

Comment: edit_email.addTextChangedListener(new InputValidator(edit_email));

Comment: I need, when i click button it should not route me on next page until EditText completed with correct validation

Comment: I got the solution. First I store EditText value in String email;  ,then I put if(!email.endsWith("gmail.com" ) in If block . I am sorry to write this solution in Comment box because I am not authorized to give Answer. Thanks